# Linear Maps Thought of as Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am reading a paragraph from an introductory Linear Algebra book, and I am not exactly grasping what the author means. The excerpt is as follows:

> Let $F^{m,n}$ denote the set of all $m$-by-$n$ matrices with entries in some generic field $F$. Each $m$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ induces a linear map from $F^{n,1}$ to $F^{m,1}$, namely the matrix multiplication function that takes $x\in F^{n,1}$ to $Ax\in F^{m,1}$. **The result above can be used to think of every linear map (from one finite-dimensional vector space to another FDVS) as a matrix multiplication map after suitable relabeling via the isomorphism given by $\mathcal{M}$.** Specifically, if $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and we identify $v\in V$ and $\mathcal{M}(v)\in F^{n,1}$, then the result above says that we can identify $Tv$ with $\mathcal{M}(T)\mathcal{M}(v)$.

The notation for $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{L}(\cdot,\cdot)$ can be found in the below reference's page 84-85.

**My Question:** What does the bold statement mean? Can someone explain more clearly?

Reference:
Axler, Sheldon J. *Linear Algebra Done Right*, New York: Springer, 2015.

Comment: Every matrix $A \in F^{m,n}$ induces by matric multiplication $x \in F^{n,1} \mapsto Ax \in F^{m,1}$ a linear map. And the bold statement essentially tells you, that you get all linear maps $F^{n,1} \to F^{m,1}$ from this. Now I assume on page 84-85, the author has shown that every finite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to a vector space of the form $F^{n,1}$ for some $n$. Hence he says that every linear map on finite dimensional vector spaces can be thought of as matrix multiplication.

Comment: Check out the second half of my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3177904/248286

Comment: To both thanks. @TheoBendit I have yet to read more carefully, but the graph really looks cool and I hope it sheds more light on my thought process!